# react native snap carousel tinder animation not working for multiple slides getting hanged

Tags: react-native, swipe-gesture

I have installed `react-native-snap-carousel` and I am using it's tinder effect. 
    I have added 6 slides as a carousel data. It is perfectly fine for top 3 slides after that it's touch work only slide top right corner. 
    I find many other library of carousel but I need to remove card in 1 direction and add the same card in reverse direction in the card stack.

Here is my code: Please help me and here is video which i can achieved by it.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/50t76ordotsuvrf/Animation.mov?dl=0

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Image, 
    Platform, Dimensions,
    ImageBackground
} from 'react-native';
import styled from "styled-components/native"; // Version can be specified in package.json
import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';

   // here is my data array 


     init() {
            this.state = {
                videos: [
                    {
                        id: "WpIAc9by5iU",
                        thumbnail: require('../../img/whitecard.png'),
                        title: "a",
                        slideNumber: "1"

                    }, {
                        id: "sNPnbI1arSE",
                        thumbnail: require('../../img/whitecard.png'),
                        title: "the",
                        slideNumber: "2"
                    }, {
                        id: "VOgFZfRVaww",
                        thumbnail: require('../../img/whitecard.png'),
                        title: "come",
                        slideNumber: "3"

                    },
                    {
                        id: "VOgFZfRVawp",
                        thumbnail: require('../../img/whitecard.png'),
                        title: "on",
                        slideNumber: "4"

                    },
                    {
                        id: "VOgFZfRVawq",
                        thumbnail: `require('./whitecard.png')`,
                        title: "see",
                        slideNumber: "5"

                    },
                    {
                        id: "VOgFZfRVaw3",
                        thumbnail: require('../../img/whitecard.png'),
                        title: "go",
                        slideNumber: "6"
                    },
                ],
            };
        }
```

Here I am rendering each item

```
    _renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
            return (

                <View style={styles.card}>
                    <View  activeOpacity={1} onPress={() => {
                        console.log("clicked to index", index)
                        this._carousel.snapToItem(index);
                    }}>
                        <CurrentVideoImage source={item.thumbnail} resizeMode={'cover'}>
                            <View>
                            <TouchableOpacity 
                                  style={[styles.container,{marginTop:20}]}
                                                  onPress={() => this.setState({isView:!this.state.isView})}>
                                    <Image source={require('../../../arrownext.png')} style={stylesButton.imageCamera}/>
                                </TouchableOpacity>

                                   <Text 
                                    style={styles.label}>{item.title}</Text>

                            </View>
                        </CurrentVideoImage>
                    </View>

                    {/*<NextVideoImage source={{ uri: this.state.currentVideo.nextVideoId }}/>*/}

                </View>
            );
        }
```

Now it is my carousel code.

```
     return(
        <CarouselBackgroundView style={styles.content}>

                        <Carousel
                            ref={(c) => {
                                this._carousel = c;
                            }}
                            data={this.state.videos}
                            renderItem={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
                            onSnapToItem={this.handleSnapToItem.bind(this)}
                            sliderWidth={width}
                            itemWidth={290} //256
                            containerCustomStyle={{ overflow: 'visible' }}
                           contentContainerCustomStyle={{ overflow: 'visible' }}
                            layout={'tinder'}
                            firstItem={0}
                            layoutCardOffset={16} //For showing card deck height.
                        />

                    </CarouselBackgroundView>
    );
```

Here my view css

```
     const CurrentVideoImage = styled.ImageBackground`
      width: 290;
      height: 500; 
      border-radius: 20;
    `;

        const CarouselBackgroundView = styled.View`
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    flex-direction: column;
    justifyContent: center;
    alignItems: center;

      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    `;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set prop `removeClippedSubviews` to `false` on the `Carousel` component to solve this. Note that you'll then lose all `FlatList` optimizations - which shouldn't be a problem if you don't try to render a huge dataset.

More information about the issue can be found in this thread: https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/issues/262